# What is Talos' signal to Carol at the end of "Captain Marvel"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

At the end of *Captain Marvel* (2019), Carol left C-53 and greets Mar-Vell's Laboratory with the Skrulls aboard:

[image: Talos waving hand in circle on the controls of the Lab at Carol who is hovering in space outside of the ship; 4 other Skrulls stand next to Talos]

What is Talos' signal to Carol?

Comment: "*I'll be right here."* (and then his finger glows).

Comment: *No bad skrulls here, move  along*

Comment: "Let's get this caravan moving!"

Comment: "Let's get rolling"

Answer (score 2):

He's telling her they're about to turn around and set off. If you watch the scene below you can see that the front of Mar-Vell's Laboratory is pointed towards Earth with Carol having her back to it. Carol then turns around to look at Earth one last time and you see the Laboratory turning around in the background. When she looks back towards it, it has turned around completely and they are ready to set off now facing away from Earth.